# How do I make a Discord bot give me the role I want?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

As I said in the title I wanted to make my bot give me any rank I want.
I tried this and it doesn't work becouse of **Unresolved attribute reference 'add_roles' for class 'Client'**.

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == '$rank':
        role = get(message.server.roles, name='Człek')
        await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
```

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member), `Client` doesn't have the method add_roles, but `Member` does.

Try `await message.author.add_roles(role)`